# Can Arduino communicate a number to a Python script?

Tags: python, arduino

Ok, what I need to do is this:

When I press a button on the Arduino, it sends a number to the PC.

```
int button1 = 0;
int button2 = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    
  button1 = digitalRead(2);
  button2 = digitalRead(3);

  if (button1 == 1) 
    Serial.println(13);
  else if (button2 == 1) 
    Serial.println(14);
}
```

Then, a Python script reads that signal, and does something different based on which number it received.

```
import keyboard
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600)

while True:
    if ser.read == 13:
        keyboard.press_and_release ('f13')
        while True:
            if ser.read != 13:
                break
    
    if ser.read == 14:
        keyboard.press_and_release ('f14')
        while True:
            if ser.read != 14:
                break

ser.close()
```

I wanted to say that I'm a newbie and this is probably quite easy to do, but I tried this and other versions of it, but it never works.

One of the other things I tried is this:

```
import keyboard
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=.1)

while True:
        
    data = ser.readline()[:-2]
    
    if data:
        print (data)
    
    if data == 13:
        print(13)
        keyboard.press_and_release ('f13')
        while True:
            if ser.read != 13:
                break
    
    if data == 14:
        print(14)
        keyboard.press_and_release ('f14')
        while True:
            if ser.read != 14:
                break

ser.close()
```

With this, it does print something with `print (data)`, it prints `b'13'`, but writing `if data == "b'13'":` changes nothing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: b here represents its encoded as bytes.  So you should do something like data=data.decode("utf-8"). And then check if data== "13"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino is sending an `EOL` with the number, and you will have to strip that off.

Try something like `data = data.decode("utf-8").rstrip()` which should give you "13" without the return at the end.

You can then convert that to an `int` with `int()` or `int.from_bytes()`, or just compare to it directly as it is (with the quotes).